# Mapserver: avoid symbols to be cut

Tags: symbology, mapserver

I use an arrow as a symbol to follow lines, but in several cases, symbols are cut (when line features are too small or changing direction). Here is an example of the result on my Web site:

[image]

Here is my portion of code from my mapfile:

```
CLASS
    NAME "Water pipe"
    STYLE
        COLOR 0 0 0
        WIDTH 3
    END
    STYLE
        SYMBOL "wp_arrow"
        ANGLE AUTO
        SIZE 12
        INITIALGAP 20
    END
END
```

Any idea on how to prevent the symbols to be cut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found that by using `GAP -20` instead of `INITIAL GAP 20`, the symbols are not cut... The sign « - » allows symbols to follow lines orientation. But the spacing between symbols is not regular at all. I will post another question on this topic specifically.